# 'Skyrim HD - 2K Textures' mod installed via NMM not showing up in the game launcher

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, nexus-mod-manager

I've installed mods via the Workshop for Skyrim on Steam just fine, but I'm trying to install [Skyrim HD - 2K Textures](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/607/?) from the Nexus, and despite being listed as successfully installed in the NMM, it isn't showing in the Data Files menu of my Skyrim game launcher, and isn't being applied to the game itself.

How do I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Are the .esp files for 2k HD inside your Skyrim\Data folder?

Comment: could it be that the mod directly replaces certain texture files in your skyrim folder and doesn't have a .esp?

Comment: You may also need to check "include loose files." Not sure though, I use Mod Organizer. So much better :P

Answer (score 3):

The mod [Skyrim 2k HD](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/607/) does not contain an ESP file, it's just a collection of textures and should work fine by just extracting the zip files into your data folder.